# Is there a way to set network image as a wallpaper using Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to create a Wallpaper app using flutter, and without a doubt, setting an image as wallpaper is the prime function of any wallpaper app.

But I don't know how to use an image as a wallpaper on android's Home Screen since I am new to flutter. Moreover, the image is supposed to be retrieved from a URL. Is there something like `wallpaperManager` for flutter? And if there is, then how can I use that?

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: After thorough reading, I have edited the question. Can you please help me out?